# Pointers of vectors to objects

Tags: c++

I want vector of that points to object (class name is ScoreKeeper. My goal is store the players names and scores and and write them into a file. In this case, MY QUESTION IS: How do you access the object's data members.  Here is my code.

## include "std_lib_facilities_5.h"

```
class ScoreKeeper {
    
public:
    
    // Variables
    int Score;
    string Name;
    
    // Functions
    void SetScore(int number)
    {
        Score = number;
        return;
    }
    void SetName( string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return;;
    }
    
    ScoreKeeper( int nn = 0, string ss =" "): Score(nn), Name(ss){}                 // Constructor
    ~ScoreKeeper() {};                                                              // Destructor
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const ScoreKeeper &player);
    
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ScoreKeeper& player){
    os << player.Name << " " << player.Score;
    return os;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
   
    vector<ScoreKeeper*> Players;
    
    ScoreKeeper Player1 = new ScoreKeeper;
    ScoreKeeper Player2 = new ScoreKeeper;
    
    Player1->SetScore(300);
    Player1->SetName("Pape");
    
    Player2->SetScore(200);
    Player2->SetName("Yamadou");
    
    Players.push_back(Player1);
    Players.push_back(Player1);
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        cout << "Player: " << Players[i]->Name << " " << Players[i]->Score << endl;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ofstream ost {"mydata.txt"};
    
    if(!ost) error("can't open output file ", "mydata.txt");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Players.size(); ++i){
        ost << Players[i].Name << " " << Players[i].Score << endl;
    }
    ost.close();

}
```

Comment: You need to ask about a specific problem you are having.  There are at least 3 questions above all of which are a bit vague.

Comment: You are storing pointer variables in your vector but then you are trying to access the variables using "." operator instead of ->

Comment: This is pretty unclear, as you're already doing what you seem to be asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what is the error that you are getting. From what I see, you have a vector that stores pointers to ScoreKeeper class. new operator returns a pointer reference and your code should be changed from

```
ScoreKeeper Player1 = new ScoreKeeper;
ScoreKeeper Player2 = new ScoreKeeper;
```

to

```
ScoreKeeper* Player1 = new ScoreKeeper;
ScoreKeeper* Player2 = new ScoreKeeper;
```

Also when you are reading from the vector use "->" instead of "." operator.